# Cavity decay rate dependence on frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, photons, cavity-qed, laser-cavity

Photons inside an imperfect cavity will decay outside with a rate proportional to the peak width $\delta \omega$. A spectrum of such a cavity (with different quality factors) is shown below [image: Allowed modes]

My question is: Do photons with a frequency of 0.5 in the picture decay at a different rate than photons with a frequency of 1? Differently put, do the photons with frequencies "that are more allowed" inside the cavity decay faster or at the same rate as other photons?

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say the photons are decaying (what would a photon decay into?).  Instead, the peaks in your plot are resonances in the EM energy density in the cavity, and the width of the resonance indicates how long the resonance will take to go away (=decay to 1/e of its peak value) if you turn off the excitation of the cavity.  A narrow resonance of frequency full width at half max of $\Delta \nu$ takes more time $\Delta t$ to go away by the uncertainty relation $\Delta \nu \Delta t\approx 1$. This "decay" time $\Delta t$ is usually expressed as the number Q of oscillation periods $\Delta t=Q/\nu$. Plugging this into the uncertainty relation gives $Q=\nu / \Delta \nu$.

At frequencies between the resonances there is still nonzero energy density because EM plane waves are still bouncing between the cavity walls (loosing a little bit of intensity with each bounce).  However, the electric fields of the bouncing waves are not in phase and do not add up coherently.  At a resonant frequency, the distance between cavity walls is an integer number of half wave lengths, the incident and reflected wave are in phase, and the electric field becomes a standing wave with one or more humps which just go up/down in time.  For a given number of plane wave bounces, the coherent addition of electric fields results in a larger $E^2$ (energy density peak in your plot) than the off resonance incoherent sum.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is based on a misunderstanding about how to reconcile the frequency and the time domain.

The shown graph is a **transmission spectrum**, that is the transmitted intensity as a function of frequency. This essentially quantifies what fraction of the input intensity is transmitted when the cavity is pumped continuously with a plane wave of the given frequency. That is, the transmission spectrum is a **steady state quantity**. Therefore, there is a priori no notion of time in this picture.

However, time domain properties are connected by Fourier transform relations. As such, one can draw conclusions about the dynamics of certain wave packets or initial states in the time domain from the transmission spectrum.

In particular, the strong peaks are associated with so-called **resonances**. These are particularly long-lived field distributions that can be thought of as meta-stable states.

Let us look at an example. If we shoot a pulse at the cavity which has a central frequency of 1 (first resonance peak) and is much *shorter* than the mode lifetime $\tau$ (proportional to the inverse of the resonance width $\gamma$), one essentially populates that long-lived field distribution. This field distribution then decays on the time scale $\tau$. Interestingly, if the incident pulse is at a frequency of 0.9, this field distribution will also be populated (with a smaller amplitude) and is the longest to survive. Therefore, in a sense, all incident pulses with a frequency in the vicinity of a given mode peak will have a similar survival time in the cavity up to transient detuning dynamics.

Comment: "The OP is based on a misunderstanding about how to reconcile the frequency and a time domain." How so?

Comment: @Hans-UlrichRudel From the OP: *„Do photons with a frequency of 0.5 in the picture decay faster than photons with a frequency of 1?“* - This question mixes frequency an time domain. Photons at a given frequency are steady states with a given plane wave coming from infinity, so - strictly speaking - they don‘t decay at all.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, and the decay rate is proportional to difference of frequency and peak frequency like variation or deviation is square of difference between variable and expectation value.

One thing I am disagree with is only single frequency could sustained in cavity, not its integral multiple. Otherwise you would see multiple peak in radiation spectrum.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/409139)